# Python If Statement question login system easy

Tags: python

The first thing to do is write "1" and then enter username and password. After that, the max number of account is 1 and you can then use the "2" to login.
First time asking a question so I am sorry if this is like a dumb question or something. My code is as following:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LosyV.jpg - NEW LINK

Code:

```
print("Type 1 for Create user. Type 2 for login")
Choice = input("Number here: ")

if Choice == ("1"):
print("Welcome to the Create a user interface")
Username = input("Username: ")
Password = input("Password: ")

if Password.count("!") > 0:
   print("Not valid - no special characters!")
else:
  file = open("account.txt", "w")
  file.write(Username)
  file.write("\n")
  file.write(Password)
  file.close()
elif Choice == ("2"):


print("Welcome, please type your Username and Password")
Loginu = input("Write username here: ")
Loginp = input("Write password here: ")
file = open("account.txt", "r")
first_line = file.readline()
if Loginu == first_line:
print("you're logged in")
else:
print("fail")
```

It's very basic and so on. What I don't understand is why the if Loginu == first_line can't read the first_line variable... It just jumps directly to else:

I hope it helps and I know my code is very basic lol.

Comment: I can't seem to view your image on imgur, please could you paste in your code onto the actual question? Thanks. If you want to paste in code, you should use ``` followed by another ``` at then end. We can't help you at the moment without any code to go off of!

Comment: I don't get it. How come you know how to paste a web link into your question, but not your code.

Comment: @quamrana he's a new contributor he probably doesn't know how it works.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. How come the OP knows how to paste a web link? Surely that is twice as hard as pasting code.

Comment: I tried to paste my code but it wouldn't let me. It said I did all sorts of things wrong

Comment: I've updated it with code :) Thanks a bunch for all of the comments - that's really fast :D

Comment: _What I don't understand is why the if Loginu == first_line can't read the first_line variable... It just jumps directly to else:_ What do you mean by _can't read_ ? As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, unless there is a good reason not to do so.

Comment: @AMC Well I wrote Loginu == asd and what's on the first line is = asd. So it should be that Loginu == first_line. I even printed first_line just after the if statement and it said first_line printed is asd..

Comment: @AlexanderSsk _Well I wrote Loginu == asd and what's on the first line is = asd. So it should be that Loginu == first_line. I even printed first_line just after the if statement and it said first_line printed is asd.._ I'm still not sure I understand, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

My advice:

1. follow pep8, use meaningful names for variables
2. split your code into functions
3. use infinite loop for your "menu"
4. even better use some package that helps with building such applications (click?) rather then reinvent the wheel
5. Read your file with `with open(...) as f:` context manager
6. It's probably good idea to read whole file and build dictionary instead of depending on the login to be exactly identical with first line
7. use strip() to remove white characters (like newline)
8. check that line you are looking at is not empty
9. if you've opened file without context manager for writting, you need to close it before opening it again for reading
10. use debugger to check what's exactly result of readline

Comment: I don't anything about any of those things, but I'll definitely keep it in mind for when I'm making a more modern login program... If you can even call my program for a login program :)

Comment: I'm just confused as to why the Loginu == first_line doesnt work

Comment: my textfile consists of:
Nmuse \n
password

Comment: 1. You haven't closed the file after write, so readline may have resulted in empty string or whatever; 2. there may be some white (not normally visible) characters. 3. See point 10 I've added - debugger is your friend here ;)